# How to feed vector elements to a template

Tags: c++, templates, vector

I need to use a list of elements of the same type as a template argument so I'm using a vector but I'm not sure how to make this work

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>
#include <vector>

template <uint8_t VAL>
void foo()
{
    std::cout << "__" << std::endl;
};

template <>
void foo<3>()
{
    std::cout << "OK" << std::endl;
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<uint8_t> v = { 2, 4, 5, 2, 3, 55 };
    for (auto &k : v) {
        foo<k>();
    }
    return (0);
}
```

the compiler basically complains about `k` not being `a constant expression`, the problem is that I have no idea about how to modify this to make this work, I need some data structure to iterate on, so I need to keep the vector, I need a template to simplify my life, so the more I see this the more I feel trapped in an infinite loop.

Comment: No, this is not a use case for a template. This is a use case for `if (i == 3) cout << "OK";`.

Comment: @H2CO3 what do you mean exactly ? You can template a numeric value, that's for sure, that overload with `<3>` is there just to check something on the template call. I need to template a numeric value.

Comment: @userXXX I know you can use an **integer** (not any number) as a template argument. Not a variable though, only a compile-time constant. What I am saying is that I don't see the necessity for a template. This may very well be an XY problem.

Comment: Templates must be resolved at compile time. That means anything you use as a template argument must be a compile-time constant. That doesn't just mean the value is set at compile time, but that it's syntactically used as a constant, not just the value of a normal variable (as you've done here).

Comment: @JerryCoffin yes, infact my problem is how to turn that vector into a constant-compile-time set of values, the real problem it's not really about templates.

Comment: @H2CO3 are you suggesting a switch-case statement ? What are you suggesting ?

Comment: @user2485710 If you want to map integers to strings, use `std::(unordered_)map<int, std::string>`. But if that's not what you want, then again, it's hard to show you a good solution without knowing what eaxctly you are trying to do.

Comment: @H2CO3 i have to template a function `foo(uint8_t u)` because i need to call this function for all this values, that's it, no string, just 1 value, no mapping, no nothing really different from this prototype. The point is that templates are giving me the option to specify some special cases that I can overload and so i can modify the behaviour of `foo` for some given values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a variadic template to get rid of actually storing your list in a vector, so you'd just pass the  values directly to the variable function template:

```
#include <iostream>

void print(int t) {
    static char const *s [] = { "__", "OK" };
    std::cout << s[t == 3];
}

void print() {}

template<typename... Args>
void print(int n, Args ... args) {
    print(n);
    print(args...);
}

int main() {
    print(2, 4, 5, 2, 3, 55);
}
```

Result:

```
________OK__
```

As you can see, however, this still has to evaluate equality to `3` at run-time. I hesitate to say it *can't* be done with template specialization, but at least offhand, I don't see *how* to do it, if its possible.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be using a template if whatever needs to go `<here>` cannot be deduced on compile time trivially. In this case, `k` is not a constant expression, so you cannot use it as a template argument.

Templates are not a magic hammer. They have a lot of use-cases, but you can't use them for absolutely everything.

In this particular snippet of code, `foo` should be defined as `void foo(uint8_t)`.

---

> yes, infact my problem is how to turn that vector into a constant-compile-time set of values, the real problem it's not really about templates.

You might be able to pull this off using variadic templates. Instead of using the vector, you would use the integral constants directly in a variadic template (`foo<2, 4, 5, 2, 3, 55>`).

I'm not very keen on them, so this'll take a while.

**edit:** Jerry beat me to it.

Comment: but i can easily overload a template to modify the behaviour for a single value, I can't do that with other solutions like the one that you are suggesting.

Comment: It simply is not possible to use runtime values as template parameters. Templates are compile-time features. Hence the need for constant expressions.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want a way to iterate over a compile-time constant list of integral values:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>

template <uint8_t VAL>
inline void foo()
{
    std::cout << "__" << std::endl;
}

template <>
void foo<3>()
{
    std::cout << "OK" << std::endl;
}

template <uint8_t... Values>
struct FooHelper {
  static void foo_all() {
  }
};

template <uint8_t First, uint8_t... Rest>
struct FooHelper<First, Rest...> {
  static void foo_all() {
    foo<First>();
    FooHelper<Rest...>::foo_all();
  }
};

template <uint8_t... Values>
void foo_all()
{
    FooHelper<Values...>::foo_all();
}

int main()
{
    foo_all<2, 4, 5, 2, 3, 55>();
}
```

Although I honestly don't see the use case for it.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler has no possibility to infer the possible values for k at compile time, so I can't see how this could work ?

Comment: that's what I need to fix, I usually don't make questions on things that are already working :D

Answer (score 0):

Nope, that won't work for non-constant expressions. Just make it a plain old function:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>
#include <vector>

void foo(uint8_t VAL)
{
    if(VAL == 3)
        std::cout << "OK" << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << "__" << std::endl;
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<uint8_t> v = { 2, 4, 5, 2, 3, 55 };
    for (auto &k : v) {
        foo(k);
    }
return (0);
}
```